# html css div mobile display

Tags: html, css, mobile, display

I have an img in a div set as a background with the following css:

```
#div1{
background: url(../img/img1.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index:-100;
}
```

This div dispalys the img perfectly in the center of the  screen.
My second div with text has the following css:

```
#div2 {
min-height: 200px;
background: black;
opacity: 0.9;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
top: 494px;
}
```

The divs display fine on my PC. However when I open the site on my mobile, the div with the text does not display. After zooming out you can see that the div is underneath the div with the img. Why is this so since the z-indexes are given and what can I do to change this?

Comment: Did you try increasing the `z-index` value to positive in `div2`? Also try adjusting the height for both divs.

Comment: haha. Thanks a lot! It has worked. But why would this be the case since the z index was still bigger than that of the first div? Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: I just searched to find out the minimum value for `z-index` but could not find it to understand the reason. But anyway, I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just increase the `z-index` value to positive.

```
#div2 {
min-height: 200px;
background: black;
opacity: 0.9;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
position: relative;
top: 494px;
}
```